# Athletes compete in javelin throwing, one after the other, throwing it at independent distances that are all exponentially

Tags: probability

Athletes compete in javelin throwing, one after the other, throwing it at independent distances that are all exponentially distributed with parameter $\lambda$. The first competitor will lead the competition until the $N$ opponent behind him throws the handlebars to a greater distance and takes the lead. Calculate $E(N)$.

What I tried: Let $X_i$ be the result of competition $i$. We know that $X_i\sim\exp(\lambda)$. I tried to use $E\left(N\right)=E\left(E\left(N|X_{1}=x\right)\right)$. But how do I represent $N$ to be related to $X_1$? As I understand I want the first player so $X_N>X_1$.

Really struggling with this question. First time I'm seeing a random variable in an index. How do I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Think in the following way:

You are first and  you get a distance $x$

Conditioned to your distance, $N$ follows a geometric distribution with parameter $P(Y>x)=e^{-\lambda x}$

That is

$$(N|X=x)\sim Geo(e^{-\lambda x})$$

with mean $E(N|X=x)=e^{\lambda x}$

Using Expectation's properties you get

$$E(N)=E[E(N|X=x)]=E(e^{\lambda x})=\int_0^{\infty}e^{\lambda x} \lambda e^{-\lambda x}dx=\infty$$

Comment: Are you sure? Is says $E(N)=\infty$

Comment: @vesii :  I realized now that it is $\infty$. Answer edited